# C++ Class returns reference with new address

Tags: c++, class, reference

For the past 24 hours I have been going through the book "Sam's Teach Yourself C++ in 24 Hours", and the following code gives me confusion. The overloaded operator ++ returns a reference to a const Counter object. Thus, I expect that the Counter object called "a" will have the same address as Counter object called "c", which was returned to "a" using the ++ operator (after incrementing a member). But after running this simple code you can see that the addresses of "a" and "c" are different. Why is this so, since "a" is a reference to "c", and thus should have the same address?

```
#include <iostream>

class Counter
{
public:
    Counter();
    ~Counter(){}
    int getValue() const { return value; }
    void setValue(int x) { value = x; }
    void increment() { ++value; }
    const Counter& operator++();

private:
    int value;
};

Counter::Counter():
value(0)
{}

const Counter& Counter::operator++()
{
    ++value;
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Counter c;
    std::cout << "The value of c is " << c.getValue() 
        << "\n";
    c.increment();
    std::cout << "The value of c is " << c.getValue() 
        << "\n";
    ++c;
    std::cout << "The value of c is " << c.getValue() 
        << "\n";
    Counter a = ++c;
    std::cout << "The value of a: " << a.getValue();
    std::cout << " and c: " << c.getValue() << "\n";

    std::cout << "address of a: " << &a << "\n" << "address of 
c: " << &c << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a` is not `c`, it's also not a reference to `c`. `a` is a copy of `c`. It seems like you may be letting preconceptions from Java or another similar language affect your understanding of c++.

Comment: `Counter a` and `Counter c` are different objects so they have different addresses.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't be too disappointed if you're nothing more than a hack at the end of 24 hours. C++ takes a lot of time and practice to get figured out.

Comment: @user4581301 I was just kidding about the 24 hours part :)

Comment: @SeanDaley Not a worry. I was mocking the name of the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Thus, I expect that the Counter object called "a" will have the same address as Counter object called "c", which was returned to "a" using the ++ operator.

That would be true if you capture the return value by reference, such as

```
Counter const& a = ++c;
```

When you use

```
Counter a = ++c;
```

A new object is constructed from the return value of `++c`. Hence, `c` and `a` end up having two different addresses.

Comment: So although the ++ operator is defined such that it returns a reference to a const Counter, its returned value can go into the completely independent new object called "a". Why not just define the ++ operator such that it returns a const Counter object then, instead of a reference to a const Counter?

Comment: @SeanDaley There are some really neat things you can do with that returned reference. While it might not be as useful with the  your class, it's the special sauce that makes `>>` and  `<<` chain when doing formatted IO. In your case for `++` you could still do stuff like `c++.getValue();`